# Converting to decimal returns the numbers concated

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a string to decimal but it just removes the (.) , making the string a whole number like an integer.

Example : input 123.12  output 12312, if I use the debug.write it show's 123.12 but when the convert take place it changes to 12312.

I have tried both methods but neither worked :

```
Convert.ToDecimal(InputTextbox.Text);
decimal.Parse(InputTextbox.Text);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suspect you are using a localization that uses the `,` as a decimal separator instead of `.`

Comment: You are right, I searched a bit more and it seems the the best practice is to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture in parse.